# Cygwin output in terminal differs from Windows console

Tags: cygwin

I have a program which is displaying some output when run in the Windows console (conhost.exe) and no output at all when run under Cygwin with the exact same argument.

What could cause such an issue ?

Also I tested called `$ C:/Windows/zip.exe --help` and they both returned the same output. (maybe this is not standard but error output though)

The command line is:

```
./Bin/Release/MyExe.exe regtest ./QCE/RegressionTests/AutoTests/AutoGenerated/T1/RegTest_PV_Loan.tst
```

The program is a non standard program for which we do not have the source code.

EDIT: I have been told that the program checks if it is running in a console using this call which returns false in Cygwin:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683167(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: what kind of program is it? Also post here the full command lines that you are using

Comment: Better post the output - and explain the differences.

Comment: One is the result of the reg tests and one is no output at all. I can put the results of these reg tests but I am not sure it is very relevant in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program was checking if it was running in console mode using the function `GetConsoleMode`. Unfortunately this returns false in bash under Cygwin.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683167(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It must be a problem with paths. Check:

- The content of the environment variable PATH on both cmd.exe and Cygwin
- Try with relative or absolute paths
- Use [Sysinternals' Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to "spy" on what the MyExe.exe program is doing. It should display things like errors when trying to open a file.
- You may find something useful in the manpage of the 'cygpath' command too

Comment: I think it must be doing something like checking if it is running in a real console and not outputting anything when it is not the case.

Comment: why do you need to run it from cygwin?

Comment: I do not need per se, but I am much familiar with bash than DOS commands. I need to do some scripting to run the things and change the order of what is run depending of the output.

Comment: try "CMD /C command" instead of "command" or creating a .bat file

Comment: I will do, just stuck with some other urgent issues atm

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with Cygwin running many DOS programs (especially compiled with a Borland compiler) in an X11 xterm but not under the non-X cygwin console window.  For example /UTES/zip.exe displays nothing (not even an error message).

Workaround:
I did find that redirecting output with /UTES/zip.exe > /tmp/some.file gets the required text output, yet /UTES/zip.exe | more hangs (as does any other piped command... to sort, lpr, etc.) I could use CMD but CMD /c program.exe doesn't work for me and running programs interactively from the CMD shell othere than cygwin executables or CMD-builtins also output nothing but the command name. The best solution for me has been to avoid X for these programs, unfortunately.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: My workaround can be useful, even if it is not a real solution... using somecommand > somefile can help if you cannot change anything else; the surprise though is that somecommand | more doesn't do the trick. The true solution surely is to modify the programs that don't work; it isn't a problem with paths and the CMD /C trick doesn't help.

Comment: Just to be clear: my suggestion is to use **non-X11** cygwin. The workaround redirecting output to a file can still be useful for seeing output if there are no other options available. The key is to get the software to write to (slow-but-standard) stdout, not do fast screen-memory writes, despite it thinking (reasonably, I guess) that it is writing to the console. In the programs I tried redirected output to a file (but not piping to another executable) forced the answer that GetConsoleMode failed to answer appropriately.